# How to check settings for when the last time all document libraries we cached

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint Online.  I have am using the following **Query text (KQL)** to fetch specific document libraries.

```bash
contentClass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary
Title:"Items ABC*" NOT Title:"Items ABC ALT*"
```

All document libraries are displaying, except for the one I created 2 days ago from today.

Where in SharePoint Online, can I go see when was the last time SharePoint re-cached all document libraries, OR if its still trying to re-cycle through all of my document libraries?

Comment: What is the name of your new document library? Try manually reindexing your document library (and wait for 1 hour maybe): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/crawl-site-content#reindex-a-document-library-or-a-list. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I feel like I found my own mistake. The document library "name" and title are two different things, and I have a feeling that is why I am not seeing the latest document library listed with Query text....its original name is not consistent with how I named the other document libraries... Re-creating the document library now, with the proper "name" format, to see if that is the fix...

Comment: Make sure the document library title is starting with `Items ABC`. You can check the library title from library view (highlithed title example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3nnk.png). Let me know if this works for you so I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP, I just had to wait longer.  I wonder if the crawling process is faster if there are no spaces in the document library "names"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint Online, it's not possible to see the current status of the SharePoint Search crawler. If you have access to this library, search should have indexed it by now and it should be returned. You could try adding some items to the affected library, if it's empty.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but its not empty.  How is is that the document library "is" showing up under Site Contents, but "not" when I reference it with Query text (KQL)? Makes no sense to me...

Comment: Because the Site Contents page returns libraries and lists in the site by querying the content database directly, where as you seem to be querying SharePoint Search for libraries which returns results from the search index.

Comment: I feel like I found my own mistake. The document library "name" and title are two different things, and I have a feeling that is why I am not seeing the latest document library listed with Query text....its original name is not consistent with how I named the other document libraries...

Comment: Thank you for answering my original question.  The document library eventually showed up, but took 3.5 days to do so.